# python pexpect not working from terminal but works find from Pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pexpect

I written one script which uses the python pexpect module, Create the SSH on the remote server and executing some commands, So I am using the following command

```
 child = pexpect.spawn(ssh root@hostname)
 child.sendline(mycomand)
 child.expect(root@hostname, timeout=None)
```

I am executing command which is taking approximately 10 mins. ten next command which is again taking 10 mins.

While running this in  pycharm debug mode it is working fine, But it is not working if running from unix terminal, so while running from terminal it is executing the line child.expect(root@hostname, timeout=None) within some seconds.

Could someone help me on this

Comment: Please verify that you are using same Python version in your `Pycharm` and while executing the command through `UNIX shell`

Comment: Can you try with child.delaybeforesend = None just after pexpect.spawn()?

Comment: there is a much more high level library that you could be using: fabric

Comment: I already used child.delaybeforesend = None it is not working also Unix shell & Pycharm python version are same python-3.4.1